# % Change Measure PowerBI DAX: not returning a value

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax, measure, rate

I am trying to create a Measure % Change using a Total Sales measure that is comprised of the sum of costs.

This is my Formula derived from a Youtube Video:

```
% Change = 
VAR CurrentValue = [Total Sales] 
VAR PreviousValue = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE('VM Export Costs'[Date].[Month]), CALCULATE([Total Sales], PARALLELPERIOD('VM Export Costs'[Date], -1, MONTH)),
    ISINSCOPE('VM Export Costs'[Date].[Quarter]), CALCULATE([Total Sales], PARALLELPERIOD('VM Export Costs'[Date], -1, QUARTER)),
    ISINSCOPE('VM Export Costs'[Date].[Year]), CALCULATE([Total Sales], PARALLELPERIOD('VM Export Costs'[Date], -1, YEAR))
)
RETURN
DIVIDE(
CurrentValue - PreviousValue,
PreviousValue
)
```

I have excluded the Hierarchy Level 'Day': As Each month only has 1 corresponding Day (the 1 of the month).

The Created Measure for Total Sales (Used in % Change Measure)
Total Sales = SUM('VM Export Costs'[Total Betrag per Server])

My Question is: If the Total Sales Measure works (by each drilled through hierarchical date level), why is the % Change only returning NULL values. The Total Sales values are graphed a flucuate accordingly month to month, quarter to quarter, year to year etc.

How do I return a % Change rate: comprised of the previous date hierachy values?

I tried the provided formula from the Video Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2ELtem2iGY

But received NULL Values for the created Measure: % Change

[image]

EXPECTED: (red, green column values based on postive % or negative % Change value)

[image]

Comment: Note: The Total Sales values are all Negative, as they are a log of charges. Incase this is of relevancy

Comment: You should always provide a data model, because DAX heavily depends on it. Without seeing your data, I can only point that you are using PARALLELPERIOD function on the wrong table (it requires a proper date table).